# migrating mongo data with rake-like tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have a rake task intended to migrate legacy db fields into a `Hash`:

```
task :degrees => :environment do
  Person.all.each do |p|
    if p['degree1'] || p['degree2']
      p.degrees = {}
      p.degrees["first"] = p['degree1'] == "Other" ? p['degree1_other'] : p['degree1'] 
      p.degrees["second"] = p['degree2'] == "Other" ? p['degree2_other'] : p['degree2']
      p.save
    end
  end
end
```

Trouble is it's extremely slow with mongo and ruby taking up 80% and 20% CPU respectively.

For simpler migrations I was able to use a mongo update like so:

```
db.people.update({},{$rename : {"url" : "website"}}, false, true)
```

This ran extremely fast. Is there any way to translate the above rake task into a mongo update or shell script?

Comment: If you want to write in Ruby and port that over to js mongo easily, grab the mongo commands from your debugger (if you're set to debug level).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a [shell script](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Scripting+the+shell):

```
db.people.update({degree1:"Other"}, { $rename : { "degree1_other" : "degree1" } }, false, true )
db.people.update({degree2:"Other"}, { $rename : { "degree2_other" : "degree2" } }, false, true )
db.people.update({degree3:"Other"}, { $rename : { "degree3_other" : "degree3" } }, false, true )

db.people.find({degrees:null}).forEach( function (doc) {
    doc.degrees = { "first" : doc.degree1, "second" : doc.degree2, "third" : doc.degree3 };
    db.people.save(doc);
});

db.people.update({degree1: {$exists : true}},{$unset:{degree1:1}},false,true)
db.people.update({degree1_other: {$exists : true}},{$unset:{degree1_other:1}},false,true)
db.people.update({degree2: {$exists : true}},{$unset:{degree2:2}},false,true)
db.people.update({degree2_other: {$exists : true}},{$unset:{degree2_other:2}},false,true)
db.people.update({degree3: {$exists : true}},{$unset:{degree3:3}},false,true)
db.people.update({degree3_other: {$exists : true}},{$unset:{degree3_other:3}},false,true)
```

It runs within a few seconds.